# Access a local sqlite database on the android itself from a PhoneGap App

Tags: android, html, cordova

I know my question eventually won't match the title I opted for the question, but I honestly didn't know how to put it as I'm new to the Android and PhoneGap environments. If this is not a programming related question please accept my apologies.

We have got a .NET application that sends TASKS to our mobile employees' netbooks via webservice. The mobile users have got a local database that gets updated with new TASKS once they login. When the TASKS are completed, the local database gets updated. If there is a stable internet connection the update is then sent to the remote database.

Now we are planning to do both Android and iPhone version of the application. I understand this is possible using PhoneGap and HTML-CSS-JavaScript, but don't know how to go about it.

If anyone has experience of implementing these sort of applications, please guide me to some links/articles. I did some search on Google but didn't get a precise answer.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

The getting started guides are all [here](http://phonegap.com/start/). Each platform requires some amount of setup because of platform-specific SDK's and so forth you must download, so I would suggest starting with iOS if you have an iPhone or Android if you have an Android phone and then once you're up and running making the switch to developing for both simultaneously.

As for the question about a SQLite database, PhoneGap should be able to do what you describe. The documents for local storage, once you get to that point, are [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage).